# How do I speed up offset calculation time in SnowFlake?

Tags: sql, limit, offset, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in SnowFlake. When I perform a `SELECT` query on it, the result set contains gigs of rows. I need to process like 10000 rows at once. Hence, I'm using a batching mechanism through offset ( I do a `SELECT *` with `LIMIT 10000 OFFSET desired_offset`).

I'm using the caching mechanism of SnowFlake to reuse the calculated result. So I run the first query (which returns gigs of rows) once, and then reuse this result with varying values of `offset`.

However, as the offset keeps getting larger, the query execution time becomes larger. Some initial benchmarking showed that query execution time was **directly proportional** to the offset. Because offset reaches gigs of value, the time taken for each query goes into minutes, and subsequently, hours. This becomes a very long process.

I'd like to know if there is a way I can optimize this process. Please note that I'm not allowed to create views on top of the result set, or store the result set as another table (i.e., I just want to have read privileges on the db).

The following should provide the gist of the queries I'm running:

The first query to get the result set:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE some_condition;
```

The subsequent queries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table(result_scan('query_id_of_first_query'))
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET desired_offset;
```

The following is the benchmarking of execution time wrt offset value:

```
10^5     | 982ms

10^6     | 1.79s

10^7     | 12.59

10^8     | 1m 57s

10^9     | 19m 41s

3*10^9   | 1h 4m 55s
```

To add some more details:

The above benchmarking is for **small** warehouse. I also tried using a **large** warehouse, and as expected, it reduced the run time to 25%.

But again, I need more of a 'software' approach than a 'hardware' approach :) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, can you expand on the "I'm not allowed to store the result set as another table"?   Does that include creating a temporary table, which is what in fact Snowflake essentially does, in a way.

What size virtual warehouse are you running this on, and are you sorting the results in query1?

Perhaps adding a pseudo column in the SELECT, ordering by it, and using it in your OFFSET queries will help you limit the amount of data processed in your OFFSET queries.  I say this because the ultimate goal is to limit the number of micro-partitions you scan in each query, so that is what I'd look in to doing as a first step.  If you can create a temporary table with cluster keys, and use those columns in your "offset" logic, you should be really good too.

I hope this helps...Rich

Comment: Yes, Snowflake does create a temporary table. But the difference is that SnowFlake cannot use any of its internal optimizations (for permanent tables, SF contains the minimum and maximum values for each partition. It escapes scanning the partition if the desired values are not in the range of the partition). So, essentially it becomes a linear scan. 

I tried to store `row numbers` as an extra column, and apply filter on top of that, but it did not help, thereby concluding that SF is not using optimizations on top of the columns of this temporary table.

Comment: I added some more details wrt warehouse size.

Comment: The temp table is the way to go, with cluster keys and sort the insert by those columns, then when you use them in your query.  Example:
create or replace temporary table tmp_xyz 
   cluster by (my_mod) 
   as (select a.*, mod(row_number() over (order by null), 8) as my_mod 
       from snowflake.account_usage.query_history a 
       order by my_mod);
select min(query_text), max(query_text) from tmp_xyz where user_name = 'USER_HERE'; --scans all micro-partitions
select min(query_text), max(query_text) from tmp_xyz where my_mod = 5;  --scans small subset of micro-partitions

Comment: That's what. I'm not allowed to create temp tables, or any tables for that matter. I'm just assuming read privileges on the db.

Comment: Confirmed, using cached query results will continue to have your issue, there does not appear to be any sort of pruning happening on them.

Comment: The only suggestion I'd have is that you'll need to work with team to allow the use of TEMP tables (not what you want to hear)
I believe sooner or later Snowflake allow all users to create temp tables, w/out any additional priviliges, because tools & client libraries like the Snowflake Spark Connector rely on temporary tables and stages very often.
At a client I work at all user accounts (both system/service accounts & "human" accounts) are allowed to create temporary 
tables in their "home" databases/schemas, even though most of their data is not housed in those "home" databases.